# Python : How to dynamically combine any number of small matrices into one big matrix

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I have these 4 matrices and I want to dynamically combine them into one big matrix by passing n: number of small matrix and output matrix row and column
example:

```
[[[ 1  2]
  [ 3  4]]

 [[ 5  6]
  [ 7  8]]

 [[ 9 10]
  [11 12]]

 [[13 14]
  [15 16]]]
```

the output matrix:

```
[[ 1  2  5  6]
 [ 3  4  7  8]
 [ 9 10 13 14]
 [11 12 15 16]]
```

I can do it manually using:

```
M = np.bmat( [[x1], [x2], [x3], [x4]] )
```

Comment: What are you asking for that `bmat` doesn't provide?

Comment: And if you want to know how bmat works, you can [read its source code](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.10.1/numpy/matrixlib/defmatrix.py#L1157-L1230)

Comment: You need to clarify whether these small arrays were created separately, or whether they are just planes of a 3d array.  Are you starting with a (4,2,2) array and transforming it into a (4,4) array, or starting with 4 separate arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think (but dont know if its right), that its best to work inplace and avoid to create new objects with new methods each time - specifically when You are doing it in loop multiple times. These examples are only for 2d matrices. But it could be easilly implemented to more dimensions. Best would be to have one big array, if its really big, prolly in numpy.memmap array. Then work on its parts. Fastest indexing (second to pointers) would be on cython memoryviews...

```
import numpy as np

def combine_matrix(*args):  
    n=len(args)
    rows,cols=args[0].shape
    a=np.zeros((n,cols*rows))
    m=0
    for i in range(n/rows):
        for j in range(n/cols):
            a[i*rows:(i+1)*rows,j*cols:(j+1)*cols]=args[m]
            m+=1

    return a

def example1():
    print '#'*10
    a=np.arange(1,17)

    n=4
    rows,cols=n/2,n/2

    lst=[]
    for i in range(n):
        ai=a[i*n:(i+1)*n]
        ai.shape=rows,cols
        lst.append(ai)

    print lst
    print combine_matrix(*lst)

def example2():
    print '#'*10
    m=24
    a=np.arange(m)

    n=6
    rows,cols=m/n/2,n/2

    lst=[]
    for i in range(m/n):
        ai=a[i*n:(i+1)*n]
        ai.shape=rows,cols
        lst.append(ai)

    print lst
    print combine_matrix(*lst)

def example3():
    print '#'*10
    m,n=36,6
    a=np.arange(m)

    arrs=np.array_split(a,n)
    for i in range(n):
        ln=arrs[i].shape[0]
        arrs[i].shape=2,ln/2

    print combine_matrix(*arrs) 

example1()
example2()
example3()
```

Answer (score 1):

2 minutes implementation (for question before edition, maybe usefull for someone):

```
import numpy as np

a=np.ones((10,10))
b=a*3
c=a*1
d=a*1.5

def combine_matrix(*args):  
    n=len(args)
    rows,cols=args[0].shape
    a=np.zeros((n,rows,cols))
    for i in range(n):
        a[i]=args[i]
    return a

print combine_matrix(a,b,c,d)
```

If sizes of arrays are huge there is place for improvement...

Comment: anserw for edited in new anserw; it would be waste to dump my 2 minutes solution xD

Answer (score 1):

[edit - I'm assuming that the small arrays are created independently, though my example is based on splitting a (4,2,2) array.  If they really are just planes of a 3d array, then some combination of 'reshape' and 'transpose' will work better.  But even such a solution will produce a copy because the original values are rearranged.]

Lets make a list of 2x2 arrays (here from a 3d array).  Squeeze is needed because this split produces (1,2,2) arrays:

```
    n = len(A)
    E = np.zeros((n,n))
In [330]: X=np.arange(1,17).reshape(4,2,2)

In [331]: xl=[np.squeeze(i) for i in np.split(X,4,0)]

In [332]: xl
Out[332]: 
[array([[1, 2],
        [3, 4]]), array([[5, 6],
        [7, 8]]), array([[ 9, 10],
        [11, 12]]), array([[13, 14],
        [15, 16]])]
```

Your `bmat` approach - corrected to produce the square arrangment

```
In [333]: np.bmat([[xl[0],xl[1]],[xl[2],xl[3]]])
Out[333]: 
matrix([[ 1,  2,  5,  6],
        [ 3,  4,  7,  8],
        [ 9, 10, 13, 14],
        [11, 12, 15, 16]])
```

A concatenation approach:

```
In [334]: np.vstack([np.hstack(xl[:2]),np.hstack(xl[2:])])
Out[334]: 
array([[ 1,  2,  5,  6],
       [ 3,  4,  7,  8],
       [ 9, 10, 13, 14],
       [11, 12, 15, 16]])
```

Since slicing works in `hstack` I could also use it in the `bmat`:

```
In [335]: np.bmat([xl[:2],xl[2:]])
Out[335]: 
matrix([[ 1,  2,  5,  6],
        [ 3,  4,  7,  8],
        [ 9, 10, 13, 14],
        [11, 12, 15, 16]])
```

Internally `bmat` (check its code) is using a version of the `vstack` of `hstacks` (contactenates on first and last axes).  Effectively

```
In [366]: ll=[xl[:2], xl[2:]]

In [367]: np.vstack([np.hstack(row) for row in ll])
Out[367]: 
array([[ 1,  2,  5,  6],
       [ 3,  4,  7,  8],
       [ 9, 10, 13, 14],
       [11, 12, 15, 16]])
```

Some how you have to specify the arrangement of these `n` arrays. `np.bmat(xl)` produces a `(2,8)` matrix (so does `hstack`).  `np.vstack(xl)` produces a `(8,2)` array.

It shouldn't be hard to extend this to work with a 3x3, 2x3, etc layout of subarrays.  `xl` is a list of subarrays.  Rework it into the desired list of lists of subarrays and apply `bmat` or the combination of `stacks`.

---

2 quick versions of 2x3 layout (a 4d `xl` array is easier to construct than a 2x3 nested list, but functionally will be the same:

```
In [369]: xl=np.arange(3*2*2*2).reshape((3,2,2,2))

In [370]: np.vstack([np.hstack(row) for row in xl])
Out[370]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  4,  5],
       [ 2,  3,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 12, 13],
       [10, 11, 14, 15],
       [16, 17, 20, 21],
       [18, 19, 22, 23]])

In [371]: xl=np.arange(2*3*2*2).reshape((2,3,2,2))

In [372]: np.vstack([np.hstack(row) for row in xl])
Out[372]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  4,  5,  8,  9],
       [ 2,  3,  6,  7, 10, 11],
       [12, 13, 16, 17, 20, 21],
       [14, 15, 18, 19, 22, 23]])
```

Comment: I dont like it if every time You create new lists and use methods. Wouldn't faster solution be inplace, on cython memoryviews?

Comment: Your answer acts like `concatenate`, except yours operates on 2 axes.  If coded in c or cython yours could save time over my repeated stacks.  List copies are no big deal since they just copy object pointers.  No solution is truly inplace if the original arrays don't already occupy a contiguous memory block.

Comment: It's possible that even without compilation, that your solution is faster than the uses of concatenation - if the number of blocks is small relative to their size.  But we'd have to do time tests.

Comment: Trully I would like to use simple methods like concentate, but only if they are outside loop. If inside, and loop is long my intuition tells me that calling python objects each time will make it longer. Most efficient will be to operate on one big array and just populate it - but only if populating is in some repetable cycle. Otherwise concentate seems to be ok.

Answer (score 1):

You can combine transposition and reshape operations:

```
In [1878]: x=arange(24).reshape(4,3,2)

In [1879]: (_,n,m)=x.shape

In [1880]: x.reshape(2,2,n,m).transpose(0,2,1,3).reshape(2*n,2*m)
Out[1880]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  6,  7],
       [ 2,  3,  8,  9],
       [ 4,  5, 10, 11],
       [12, 13, 18, 19],
       [14, 15, 20, 21],
       [16, 17, 22, 23]])
```